# How to allow my client to interact with Lists of my code without Unity software?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a fortune gift program.There is atleast 2 different fortune gift with a list of itself. Client also want to set the percentages of fortune gift by themself. I don't know how to let them do it.  How can I let them edit the list (add more GValue, edit GWeight) and create another List?

```
public class GiftValue
{
    public int GValue;
    public int GWeight;

    public GiftValue(int gvalue, int gweight)
    {
        GValue = gvalue;
        GWeight = gweight;
    }
}

public List<GiftValue> GiftwithWeight = new List<GiftValue>
{
    new GiftValue(1,        25),
    new GiftValue(2,        25),
    new GiftValue(3,        25),
    new GiftValue(5,        20),
    new GiftValue(4,        5),
};

private readonly List<int> _GiftList = new List<int>();

private void Start()
{

    foreach (GiftValue kvp in GiftwithWeight)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < kvp.GWeight; i++)
        {
            _GiftList.Add(kvp.GValue);
        }
    }

}
public int GetRandomNumber()
{
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, _GiftList.Count);
    randomnumber=randomIndex;
    return _GiftList[randomIndex];
}
```

Comment: How the editing is supposed to be done from the user's point of view? Which part of your software is on Unity and which isn't?

Comment: Surely you store those in a database somewhere, maybe generate serialized objects from them which you can download as assets?

Comment: Sorry, I just learn coding. I only just finish the above gift. Didn't learn to write database yet.@BugFinder

Comment: @trollingchar Client don't know anything about code, so I assume that I need to create a software that can Edit, Add Gift List for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would [serialize those lists as JSON](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) and load them at runtime.
 Your client can replace this file or adjust values before he starts the application.

Code would look like this.

```
[Serializable]
public struct GiftValue
{
    public int Value;
    public int Weight;
}

[Serializable]
public class GiftConfig
{
    public List<GiftValue> Gifts;
}

public void LoadConfig(string filePath) {
    string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    var giftConfig = JsonUtility.FromJson<GiftConfig>(fileContent);
}
```

JSON would look like this:

```
{ 
    "Gifts":[ 
        { 
            "Value":1,
            "Weight":25
        },
        { 
            "Value":2,
            "Weight":25
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: Added code and json